# Excel Create New Workbook and Copy Over Existing Workbook Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a new workbook and copy over a tab from my existing workbook to the new workbook.

The code below creates the workbook but the tab isn't being copied, any ideas why?

```
Sub test()
Dim wkb0 As Workbook
Set wkb0 = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
'Sheet to be copied is hidden
wbk0.Sheets("Blank_SWGR_Template").Visible = True
wbk0.Worksheets("Blank_SWGR_Template").Copy wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
wbk0.Sheets("Blank_SWGR_Template").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't this throw an error at `wbk.Sheets("Sheet_Name")` (unless you actually have a sheet "Sheet_Name" in every new workbook) ?

Comment: Search on here, there are codes shown

Comment: @Tim Williams Ah I didn't say it but yes Sheet_Name was a dynamic variable used in my code used in looping, even removing that portion still gives me the same problem though

Comment: Now you're just creating a new workbook from a copy of the sheet...

Comment: Understood, edited to what would normally be the first sheet in a new workbook.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you run that? No errors, the sheet just doesn't copy?